# Is double not equal to true?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I have a todolist app. When clicking checkbox box, the item will be moved to a completed todo section. In the completed todo section, I use double not (!!) to check if the checkbox is unchecked, then go back to incompleted section. My question is why I need to use double !!, instead of use isChecked? If I use isChecked and when uncheck the box, the todo will not go back to the incompleted section.

```
let isChecked = false

// check todo
  $('.active_todos').on('change', '.todo_check', (e) => {
    if ($('.todo_check').is(':checked')) {
      $(e.target).parent().addClass('completed')
      $('.complete_todos').append($(e.target).parent())
      isCheked = true;
      incompleteTodocount--;
      updateCount()
    }
  })

  // checked item back to actived section
  $('.complete_todos').on('change', '.todo_check', (e) => {
    if (!!isCheked) {
      $(e.target).parent().removeClass('completed');
      $('.active_todos').append($(e.target).parent());
      incompleteTodocount++;
      updateCount()
    }
  })
```

Comment: `isCheked` vs. `isChecked`. Is this just a typo?

Comment: You don't need `!!` if you're already dealing with a boolean value. That's useful for rendering something as a boolean, but also makes no sense inside an `if` which will already evaluate that expression as if it is a boolean. As in `let x = !!y` makes sense where `y` could be `0` or `1` and you want `false` or `true` respectively, but `if (!!y)` does not.

Comment: `!!` results in a Boolean ... so it coerces "falsy" values to `false` otherwise `true` - so, result of `!!` depends on what you apply it to

Comment: @tadman, yes, it's typo

Comment: @tadman, Thanks! I got the point